# How to check if there are new tags on git remote?

Tags: git

I want to see if there are any tags incoming from the remote.

Both `git fetch` and `git fetch --tags` create tags in a local repository if they do not yet exist. But I don't want to create tags, only to check whether they will be created if I do `fetch` or `pull`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Try [`git fetch --tags --dry-run`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---dry-run)

Comment: That works! Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git fetch --tags --dry-run
```

`--dry-run` makes Git show what would be done, without making any changes.

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---dry-run).

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324007/why-does-a-command-line-call-behaves-not-as-expected-when-i-am-doing-that-in-has Maybe you can provide some tips

Comment: No idea, sorry, never learnt Haskell. Bash/JS work so the problem is not in Git. Perhaps it's the way arguments are passed to the command line. Somehow only one argument is passed.